# Each php result in a table in column and not by row

Tags: php, mysql

I have some mysql data like these:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| **nomrub** | **nomsousrub** | **datefact** | **qtvol** |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  comm      |    sms         |2016-09-05    |     18    |
|  comm      |    appel       |2016-09-05    |     2h30  |
|  comm      |    data        |2015-09-05    |     550   |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

etc etc etc..

I need to create a table with the differents date by column like that:

```
   Date | 2016-09-05 | 2016-09-04 | 2016-09-03 | 2016-09-02 |
   Sms  |  18        |   57       |    652     |   458      |
   Appel|  2h30      |   5h10     |   55h20    |    32h52   |
```

I'm so stuck because I need to sort result by date and by column but in Html we can't create a table by column, only by row..

I don't want to have one query by cell ..

If anyone can help me ?

Comment: so, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Store the results in an array first, and iterate through the array to build your table.

```
$data = array();
while($row = your_msql_result) {
  $data['date'][] = $row->date;
  $data['sms'][] = $row->sms;
}

echo "<table>";

echo "<tr>
        <td>Date</td>";

foreach($data['date'] as $value)
   echo "<td>".$value."</td>";

echo "</tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sms</td>";

foreach($data['sms'] as $value)
   echo "<td>".$value."</td>";

echo "</tr></table>";
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to alter your mysql table for that

```
Query : ALTER TABLE <yourtable> ADD <fieldname> VARCHAR(20)
```

But this is not a proper way to proceed because there is a limit for mysql column size.